# TypeError: currentTodos.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can not send currentTodos array to Cardhouse I want to send currentTodos array from seach-result.component.jsx to render loop card-house.component.jsx it show error TypeError: currentTodos.map is not a function Cardhouse
C:/Users/pimdo/Desktop/BF-property/src/components/card-house/card-house.component.jsx:45

seach-result.component.jsx

```js
import React from "react";
import Pagination from '@material-ui/lab/Pagination';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Cardhouse from '../card-house/card-house.component.jsx'
class Seachresult extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 10],
      currentPage: 1,
      todosPerPage: 6,
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event, value) {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: Number(value),
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { todos, currentPage, todosPerPage } = this.state;
    // Logic for displaying todos
    const indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;
    const currentTodos = todos.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);


    // Logic for displaying page numbers
    const pageNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(todos.length / todosPerPage); i++) {
      pageNumbers.push(i);
    }

    return (
      <div>
      <Typography>Page: {currentPage}</Typography>
      <Cardhouse currentTodos={currentTodos} />
        <Pagination count={pageNumbers.length} page={currentPage} size="large" id={currentPage} onChange={this.handleClick} showFirstButton showLastButton />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Seachresult;
```

card-house.component.jsx

```js
import React from "react";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";
import HotelIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Hotel";
import BathtubIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Bathtub";
import SquareFootIcon from "@material-ui/icons/SquareFoot";
import RoomIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Room";
import HouseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/House";
import ShareIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Share";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  cardGrid: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(8),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(8),
  },
  card: {
    height: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  cardMedia: {
    paddingTop: "56.25%", // 16:9
  },
  cardContent: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
}));

export default function Cardhouse(currentTodos) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  
  return (
    <Container className={classes.cardGrid} maxWidth="lg">
        {/* End hero unit */}
        <Grid container spacing={3} style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>
          {currentTodos.map(currentTodo=> (
            <Grid item key={currentTodo} xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
              <Card className={classes.card}>
                <CardActionArea component={Link}
                to="/property-detail">
                  <CardMedia
                    className={classes.cardMedia}
                    image="https://source.unsplash.com/random"
                    title="Image title"
                  />
                  <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                    <Grid container spacing={1}>
                      <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Typography variant="h5">{"บ้านแสนสุข"}</Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Typography
                          variant="subtitle2"
                          style={{ color: "#969696" }}
                        >
                          <RoomIcon fontSize="small" />
                          {
                            "ซอย ลาดพร้าว 101 Khlong Chan, Bang Kapi District, Bangkok, Thailand"
                          }
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Typography variant="h6" style={{ color: "#26ae61" }}>
                          {"$"} {"1,900,000"} {"บาท"}
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Typography
                          variant="subtitle2"
                          style={{ color: "#969696" }}
                        >
                          <HotelIcon fontSize="large" />
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Typography
                          variant="subtitle2"
                          style={{ color: "#969696" }}
                        >
                          <BathtubIcon fontSize="large" />
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Typography
                          variant="subtitle2"
                          style={{ color: "#969696" }}
                        >
                          <SquareFootIcon fontSize="large" />
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Typography
                          variant="subtitle2"
                          style={{ color: "#969696" }}
                        >
                          <HouseIcon fontSize="large" />
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Typography
                          variant="subtitle2"
                          style={{ color: "#969696" }}
                        >
                          {"ห้องนอน 1"}
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Typography
                          variant="subtitle2"
                          style={{ color: "#969696" }}
                        >
                          {"น้องน้ำ 1"}
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Typography
                          variant="subtitle2"
                          style={{ color: "#969696" }}
                        >
                          {"256 ตารางเมตร"}
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Typography
                          variant="subtitle2"
                          style={{ color: "#969696" }}
                        >
                          {"บ้านเดี่ยว"}
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </CardContent>
                </CardActionArea>
                <CardActions>
                  <div style={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}>
                    <IconButton aria-label="share">
                      <ShareIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
                      <FavoriteIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </div>
                </CardActions>
              </Card>
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are passing to `Cardhouse` is actually a `props` object, not an array. Thus you are getting this error. Ways to resolve this is to change function Cardhouse argument like:

**Using `props`:**

```
export default function Cardhouse( props )
```

and then change the `map()` method to:

```
{props.currentTodos.map(currentTodo=> (
```

**Using Object Destructuring:**

Or, you can simply destructure the `props` object and you will not have to change anything inside the function like:

```
export default function Cardhouse({ currentTodos })
```

For more information: [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `CardHouse` component is treating `currentTodos` as the prop object instead of a prop attribute.

Change:

```
export default function Cardhouse(currentTodos) {
  // code here
}
```

into:

```
export default function Cardhouse({ currentTodos }) {
  // code here
}
```